# Finding Likert Items that Deviate

Tags: likert

I'm a bit new to this so please pardon me if I say something ill-informed.

I have a set of Likert items which assess how well participants liked different aspects of an activity. I also have a single item which assesses their overall satisfaction. I would like to identify aspects of the activity which were rated particularly well and aspects which need improvement.

My initial thought is to look for items which were rated significantly higher or lower than the overall rating, using a signed rank test.

Would this be appropriate? And if so, should I compare items against the overall rating item, or try to compute an overall rating by averaging the likert items?

Or is there a better way to answer this question?

Thanks!